# (Android Studio) Custom Action Bar Layout isnt filling whole action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fill

before setContentView()

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSupportActionBar() .getThemedContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View customActionBarView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ab, null);
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,  ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setCustomView(customActionBarView,    new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

in ab.xml
[image: image1]

in My Application

[image: image2]

int styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

</style>
<style name="ATheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.a</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.a</item>>
    <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.a" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:height">50dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#d1d1d1</item>
</style>
```

in my Application, isn't filling action bar completely

Comment: Quick question; For this activity what values do you have for the android:icon and android:logo attributes in the manifest file ?

Comment: @Jayesh Elamgodil I updated with styles.xml

Comment: Could you please try adding an entry android:logo with the same color/transparent value in your styles.xml

Comment: Sorry that it didn't work. I am not entirely sure but I have a doubt about ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT? could you try FILL_PARENT

Comment: i tried FILL_PARENT but it's not changing

Comment: Please take a look for modifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is
Change your style like this

```
<resources>

    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="AppTheme"
        parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="MyActionBar"
        parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
        <!--<item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
    </style>

</resources>
```

And your ActionBar.xml Layout like this:
**Note: if you changed 'android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"' to 'android:layout_height="match_parent"' it will not fill whole action bar width and if you changed LinearLayout to RelativeLayout with 'android:layout_height="match_parent"' Action bar will fills the entire screen**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:text="Aplication"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally :

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayOptions( ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.ab);

        View customActionBarView = actionBar.getCustomView();
```

Hope this help.