# Custom ActionBar resulting in overlapping default ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

Hello I wanted to add custom ActionBar to my application in Android using this method:

```
   LinearLayout ll_q = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.qtitlebar);
   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
   getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.question_titlebar);
```

The result is:

[image]

How to get rid of the grey area in this ActionBar and the menu button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If You are using Android Studio do the following:

1. Extend your class with Activity instead of ActionBarActivity.
2. Open your app's Manifest File and change

   ```
       android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
   ```

Comment: extanding my class with Activity does not support getSupportActionBar method, so I can't add my custom ActionBar this way

Comment: by what you are extending your class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29478494/android-studio-custom-action-bar-layout-isnt-filling-whole-action-bar

Comment: the above link might help you

Answer (score 1):

The solution is adding :

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The code should look something like:

```
actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); 
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);//set the custom view
```

in style file add below code :

```
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>


<style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set Layout as well for `Custom ActionBar` i.e.

Inflate custom actionbar view

```
LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v =inflator.inflate(R.layout.actionbar_discard_done, null);
```

then set custom view with layout param

```
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
 getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(v,params);
```

Comment: Still the same after changing.